# Angular - Submit async form

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, es6-promise

I have a submit method that calls a method and then updates the status in a string message called **errorMessage**. The submit method is like:

```
onSubmit() {

this.userProfileForm = new UserForm(this.firstName.value, this.lastName.value, this.email.value, null, this.phone.value,
  this.description.value, this.profileImage.value);

this.updateUserAttributes().then(() => {
    this.userService.updateUser(this.id, new UserModel(this.firstName.value,
      this.lastName.value, this.email.value, this.phone.value, this.description.value, null)).subscribe(
        () => this.errorMessage = 'Success');
    console.log(this.errorMessage);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('Error');
    this.errorMessage = 'Error';
  }
);
```

}

As you can see, there are logs in the method.
I'm coding a test to validate the submit method, but it is not working.

The test looks like this:

```
spyOn(cognitoService, 'updateUserAttributes').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

spyOn(userService, 'updateUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of(new UserModel(component.firstName.value,
  component.lastName.value, component.email.value, component.phone.value, component.description.value, null)));

const firstNameControl = component.profileForm.controls['firstName'];
firstNameControl.setValue('newFirstName');
firstNameControl.markAsTouched();
fixture.detectChanges();

component.onSubmit();
fixture.detectChanges();

console.log('component.errorMessage: ' + component.errorMessage);


   expect(firstNameControl.valid).toBeTruthy();
   expect(component.errorMessage).toBe('Success');
```

In the test, I'm printing also the **errorMessage** property.
In the console, the logs appear in this way:

```
'component.errorMessage: undefined'
'Success'

Expected undefined to be 'Success'.
```

The first log is the log of the test, and then the log of the method. It should be the other way around.
The method updateUserAttributes() return a Promise that is handled in the submit method, but it seems that it is not working in the test.

Do you know how can I do to make the test to wait for the end of the submit event in order to validate the property errorMessage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using **whenStable** method in the test.

The test looks now like that:

```
  it('when submit with correct result, it should ok and show an ok  message', () => {

    spyOn(cognitoService, 'updateUserAttributes').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

    spyOn(userService, 'updateUser').and.returnValue(Observable.of(new UserModel(component.firstName.value,
      component.lastName.value, component.email.value, component.phone.value, component.description.value, null)));

    const firstNameControl = component.profileForm.controls['firstName'];
    firstNameControl.setValue('newFirstName');
    firstNameControl.markAsTouched();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubmit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('component.errorMessage: ' + component.errorMessage);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(firstNameControl.valid).toBeTruthy();
      expect(component.errorMessage).toBe('Success');
    });
  });
```